# Accessing an object without storing a pointer to it in each instance

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a situation similar to the following

```
struct Cell
{
  uint16_t x, y;
  // other fields

  Cell* right();
  Cell* above();
  ...
}

class Container
{
private:
  uint16_t width, height;
  Cell* data;

public:
  Container(uint16_t width, uint16_t height) : 
    width(width), height(height), data(new Cell[width*height]) { }

  Cell* cellAt(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) { &data[x*height + y]; }
};

Container* container;

Cell* Cell::right() { return container->cellAt(x+1, y); }
...
```

I trimmed down much of code (eg range checks and whatnot) just to show the design.

Basically this allow me everywhere in the code to access neighbour cells without passing by Container object directly (which would produce more verbose code and neighbours are accesses hundreds of times all around the code base). The solution works nicely and `Container` class is not even need to be known around the code, since `Cell` is enough.

This approach has a strong limit though: it allows only one instance of `Container`. Now I find myself in the situation of wanting multiple instances of `Container`, with independent `Cell` arrays but I don't want to change the structure of the code.

I'm thinking about a smart way to allow multiple `Container`, but

- I want to keep the structure as it is
- I absolutely don't want to store a `Container*` inside each `Cell` to avoid wasting a lot memory (we're talking about million of cells)
- I want to keep it as much efficient as possible since these neighbour functions are used a lot

I was thinking about allocating `width*height + 1` `Cell` instances and use the first instance to store a `Container*` in its memory, but the problem is how to compute the address of the first Cell considering that the total width/height are fields of `Container` itself (and not known by `Cell`).

So I guess I should store at least one pointer to `Container*` for each column (they are stored by column as shown by `cellAt` function for secondary reasons useless to the question). This would waste `height*sizeof(Cell)` bytes for each `Container` which could be quite a lot but I guess there's no way with with a single pointer.

So basically I could do something like:

```
Container** container = reinterpret_cast<Container**>(&data[0]);
*container = this;
```

And then retrieve the object. Of course this is a dirty hack which could give problems on architecture which doesn't support unaligned accesses if `sizeof(Cell) % alignof(void*) != 0`.

Are there smarter solutions which I'm missing?

Comment: Store a pointer to the container in each cell that's in that container.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik he stated that he doesn't want to do that

Comment: Unrelated, are you storing your data in row-major order? I ask because if so, and `x` is to denote the selected row, `y` the selected column within that row, then `data[x*height + y]` is wrong. That should be `width`, not `height`, in that equation. If not, disregard this comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but will you mix cells accessing different containers? Because if not, you could templatize `Cell` over container (index in an array/pointer) to be used.

Comment: @WhozCraig: no, I'm storing them in column-major order for other requirements which are not relevant to the question.

Comment: I'd like to have an explanation for the downvote since I don't see the point of it.

Comment: You're talking about wasting memory with a pointer in each `Cell`, but you're having each `Cell` store its coordinates... isn't _that_ unnecessary?

Comment: For getting neighboring cells, I'd suggest having a sort of 2D iterator class, which would have a position and a pointer to the Container. (You keep track of only the coordinates of a Cell that you're currently operating on, instead of every Cell's coordinates)

Comment: @qxz: unfortunately there was no way to avoid storing them for how they are used. I could compute neighbours directly by calculating the `ptrdiff_t` between a `Cell` and the first cell but this still implies knowing the width which is known in `Container` only, but there are many others functions inside `Cell` which require to know x,y directly so it would probably become a lot more expensive.

Comment: @Jack How are Cells currently being used? It could almost certainly be adapted, although it might take a while to convert lots of existing code.

Comment: You could store `Container*` instead of `x` and `y`. You can derive the latter from the former, but not vice versa. As in, `x = (this - container->data) / container->height`, `y = (this - container->data) % container->height`

Comment: If keeping the above structure is a must, if I correctly understood your request and if you use one container at any time, you could just change the context (the container pointer). RAII might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 solutions for you.

---

Cells know they are in a contiguous 2d buffer.

Finding the first element in the lower dimension is easy.  So now you are at `(N,0)`.  If `N` is `0` we are done, we found the start of the 2d array.

The element before that is `(N-1,Last)`, where `Last+1` is the size of the lower dimension.  Now you can jump to `(0,0)`.

---

Alternatively, drop x and y from the cell, replace with container pointer.  Calculate x and y on the fly from address of `this` and container pointer.

---

If we want to get serious, we drop all redundant information.

Kill x and y.  Write a cell view type that stores a `Cell*` and a `Container*`.  Mediate all interactions with `Cell` through this view.  It calculates `x` and `y` and knows container size.  It could just do nothing but pass `Container*` pointers to each method of `Cell`.

The `CellView` then replaces `Cell*` in your codebase.  You can even override `->` to return `this` and keep most use unchanged.

```
CellView cellAt(uint16_t x, uint16_t y) { return {&data[x*height + y], this}; }

struct Cell{
//  uint16_t x, y;
  // other fields

  Cell* right(Container*);
  Cell* above(Container*);
  ...
};

struct CellView{
  // maybe: uint16_t x, y;
  Cell* cell;
  Container* container;


  CellView right()const{ return {cell->right(container), container}; };
  CellView above()const{ return {cell->above(container), container}; };
  ...
};
```

Basically move state into the "pointer" and out of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible solutions that come to mind, given the limitations you've stated:

1) For all functions which need a Container to accomplish their work, just require the Container as a parameter.

For example:

```
Cell* Cell::right(Container* container)
{
    return container->cellAt(x+1, y);
}
```

2) Instead of asking Cells about things which the Container knows, ask the Container about its Cells. In other words move the `right`, `above`, and similar functions to the Container.

For example:

```
Cell* Container::nextRightCell(Cell* from)
{
    return cellAt(from->x+1, from->y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an array of global `Container` and using polymorphism over `Cell` and over `Container` to have a template integer parameter where to store the index of the `Container`...

I don't think it's a good idea (`Cell` become a pure virtual abstract struct) but, just for fun...

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

struct Cell
 {
   uint16_t x, y;
   // other fields

   virtual Cell* right() = 0;
   //Cell* above();
 };

class Container
 {
   private:
      uint16_t width, height;
      Cell* data;

   public:
      Container(uint16_t w0, uint16_t h0, Cell * d0)
         : width(w0), height(h0), data(d0)
       { }

      Cell* cellAt(uint16_t x, uint16_t y)
       { return &data[x*height + y]; }
 };

Container * containers[10];

template <std::size_t I>
struct CellI : public Cell
 {
   Cell* right()
    { std::cout << I << std::endl; return containers[I]->cellAt(x+1, y); }
 };

template <std::size_t I>
class ContainerI : public Container
 {
   public:
      ContainerI (uint16_t w0, uint16_t h0)
         : Container(w0, h0, new CellI<I>[w0*h0])
       { }
 };


int main()
 {
   containers[0] = new ContainerI<0>(10, 20);
   containers[1] = new ContainerI<1>(20, 40);
   containers[2] = new ContainerI<2>(30, 60);
   // ...

   containers[0]->cellAt(5,5)->right(); // print 0
   containers[1]->cellAt(5,5)->right(); // print 1
   containers[2]->cellAt(5,5)->right(); // print 2
 }
```